# ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive:

Tags: json, powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I was trying to run a script that fetches JSON file from CMS endpoint, pass it on the pipeline to convertfrom-json. But, I get an error saying Invalid JSON primitive.

> ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .
>   At D:\AzureProject\SetupusingParameterfile.ps1:13 char:75
>
> > > ```
> > >  $JsonContent = Get-Content $TemplateParameterFileLocal -Raw | Conver ...
> > > ```
> > >
> > > CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
> > >          + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Structure of my JSON Parameter file was inline to how Azure Parameter file structure needs to be and sample is as below:-

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/20111-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion":"1.0.0.0",
"parameters": 
        {
            "hostingPlanName": {"value": "pilotHosting"},
            "hostingEnvironment": {"value": "pilotHostingenv"},   
            "serverFarmResourceGroup": {"value": "Pilot1H"},
            "sqlserverName": {"value": "pilotsrvrtrialrun11"},
            "administratorLogin": {"value": "sites1H"},
            "administratorLoginPassword": {"value": "abcdefg"},
            "serverName": {"value": "Pilotwebserver"},
            "databaseUsername": {"value": "pilot1Hattabc"},
            "databasePassword": {"value": "pilotdbabc1H"},
        }
}
```

Note: The purpose of this post is to share few things that came up during Azure project PoC, and hope to serve someone later.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Approach 1 : -Raw** 
Attempted using -Raw with Get-Content so that Get-Content instead of reading each line separately and storing as array, creates object.

```
 $JsonContent = Get-Content $TemplateParameterFileLocal -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

**Approach 2 : Out-String**
 Attempted with Get-Content piped to | Out-String as below:

```
$JsonContent = Get-Content $TemplateParameterFileLocal | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

**Review JSON with IDE**
Finally, I recollected the IDE notification when I had opened up the saved copy of CMS generated JSON. It had a EOF expected but if you notice the above JSON structure, it got a ',' which was causing this trouble.

I tried both -Raw and Out-String execution again, and it was working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You may also have this problem with an old version of PowerShell (5.1) if your json contains a trailing comma.

PowerShell 5.1: ❌
PowerShell Core 7.1.3: ✔

```
{
  "Key": "Value",
}
```

Error in 5.1:

> ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive: .

PowerShell 5.1: ✔

```
{
  "Key": "Value"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to specify the encoding type using IO.File, for example to load a file using Windows-1252:

```
$myObj = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($filePath, [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)) | ConvertFrom-Json
```

[Text.Encoding::GetEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=net-5.0)
[Text.Encoding::GetEncodings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencodings?view=net-5.0)

Comment: This ! Thank you a milion times mane ! I have been trying to read JSON values from .zip file and use ConvertFrom-Json to get JSON object, and you out of all answers helped me! <3

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error today in PowerShell 5.1 while reading an ASP.net core appsettings.json file with some commented out lines, e.g.

```
{
  "SomeSection": [
    //{ "Foo": 1 },
    { "Bar": 2 }
  ]
}
```

ASP.net core seems quite happy with comments in these files, but PowerShell doesn't like them. I removed the commented out lines and PowerShell was happy again.

Curiously, the invalid JSON primitive reported in the error message was a full stop (period) even though that character was nothing to do with what was wrong with the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because a JSON path value was too long. I had to put it in a different directory with a shorter path to fix this error with PS5.